# Specific advantages of using a winform rather than a WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms

Is *all* the functionality of a WinForm included in a WPF?
Are there any specific advantages of using a traditional WindowsForm rather than a WPF?

Comment: ok I'm going to invite a WinForm proponent here in @CodyGray :)

Comment: @nawfal - excellent - I'm still a bit scared; as a newbie to `c#` I feel relatively at home when developing a winforms. I have an interesting project at the moment and I would still like to be totally convinced to use a WPF rather than a Winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winforms has only few advantages over WPF:

- There are many in-box controls ready for usage (but customizing and creation of new controls is easier in WPF, also there many 3rd party libraries)
- It fits legacy systems (Win2000)
- There are more developers with experience in Winforms

All other is better on WPF.

Comment: hello - got my copy of HeadFirst and on page 110 ...lots more questions for SO as I work thought it; maybe one day I'll even answer a question!

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically you can do with Winforms almost all what you do with WPF but in some cases you need a lot more of code, in particular concerning graphics effects.

Some advantages of Winforms compared to WPF could be:

- easier technology
- very stable technology because very aged. WPF still has some *child illnesses*, for example XAML binding errors compare only in the output window and you do not get any exception.
- less freedom which may make you more pragmatic. In WPF you have a huge degree of freedom with graphics, for example customizing a control, which can be very funny but could also bring you too *waste* time (in sense of putting a lot of time in colors, brushes, animations etc..). In Winforms you probably put less time for graphics (at least my experience)

Comment: "child" ...does this mean that WindowsForms are like a parent that will eventually be replaced by the child?

Comment: I mean that WPF is still a relative young technology, at least compared to Winforms. That means you may experience some limitations when working with WPF that hopefully Microsoft will improve.

Comment: @Klaus78: XAML binding errors don't cause exceptions *by design*, and it's a very useful feature in complex UIs.  That's not a "child illness," it's a design decision.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Did you experience some child illness with WPF?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your problem.  WPF is a newer technology and provides better separation of concerns, more easily flexible rendering, and allows hardware acceleration of the UI.

The advantage of any technology is specific to the constraints and requirements of the project.  For example: one advantage of WinForms would be if you are deploying solely to Windows XP machines that don't/can't have .NET 3+, because only WinForms is available on .NET 2.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit like asking why to show a HTML Table in a Flash movie.
First of all : you can mix as you wish, even at element level (using WinFormsControlHosts). But you should ask yourself why you'd want to mix those technologies.

It sounds you are rather new to WPF, so be warned that while WPF can do all WinForms can do, a very steep learning curve lies ahead of you. Things are different in the markup world...

Reasons for mixing can only be of financial nature. You either don't have the time / money / resources to implement it in WPF or learn how to do it or your customer expects on-time-delivery and doesn't give a damn about the quality of the code. Maybe you have paid a lot of money on a 3rd party WinForms component that could save hours of nasty development.

On the other hand, there are reasons for not mixing:

- WPF supports Hardware Acceleration, WinForms is rendered Cpu-only. I haven't tested what exactly happens to the render mode when using interop.
- WPF is being updated. In .Net 4.5 it gets some more DataBinding facility (which is better than WinForms anyway). WinForms hasn't received mentionable Updates since .Net 2.0

To sum it up: Is there any reason for mixing in your case? If not so, don't.
If absolutely necessary, I would add functionality to a Winforms App by adding WPF dialogs, but would always try to avoid the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

maybe because it's easier? But I would not do winforms. Go with WPF. ANd you are not forced to do MVVM if you think it's too hard. And MVVM can be overkill for small applications.

Comment: Not necessarily. MVVM is a pattern for separating code in such a way that the UI and the data can be manipulated independently. It doesn't require the use of XAML, since pretty much any XAML can be rewritten C#.